# Facebook Links without browser

Tags: c#, facebook, webrequest

I've read a lot of post on here, and other sites, but still not getting any clarification of my question. So here goes.

I have a Facebook link that requires you to be logged in. Is there a way using .Net (C#) that I can use Facebook API or something to "click" this link without a browser control.

Essentially, I have an application that I wrote that detects certain Farmville links. Right now I'm using a browser control to process the links. However, it's messy and crashes a lot.

Is there a way I can send the url along with maybe a token and api key to process the link?

Does anyone even understand what I'm asking? lol.

Comment: Sorry, I don't, but I'm a noob. Could you clarify a bit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclaimer: I don't know what Facebook's API looks like, but I'm assuming it involves sending HTTP requests to their servers. I am also not 100% sure on your question.

You can do that with the classes in the `System.Net` namespace, specifically `WebRequest` and `WebResponse`:

```
using System.Net;
using System.IO;

...

HttpWebRequest req = WebRequest.Create("http://apiurl.com?args=go.here");

req.UserAgent = "The name of my program";

WebResponse resp = req.GetResponse();

string responseData = null;

using(TextReader reader = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream())) {
    responseData = reader.ReadToEnd();
}

//do whatever with responseData
```

You could put that in a method for easy access.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your are hacking something... but here goes.

You might want to try a solution like [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/), which is normally used for testing websites.

It is a little trouble to setup, but you can programmatically launch the facebook website in a browser of your choosing for login, programmatically enter username and password, programmatically click the login button, then navigate to your link.

It is kind of clunky, but get's the job done no matter what, since it appears to facebook that you are accessing their site from a browser.

I've tried similar sneaky tricks to enter my name over and over for [Publisher's Clearing House](http://pch.com), but they eventually wised up and banned my IP.